# Chart.js var in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables, charts

I am using chart.js to create dynamic Doughnut charts and wish to build the data input of the charts into a CMS, pulling the data through using 'data-rating' in the HTML.

In my jQuery I have created two variables to make the chart output values out of 5 E.G. `1/5`, `2/5`, `3/5`, `4/5`, `5/5`.

When I just type the numbers in manually into the array it works fine, but putting variables into the array doesn't seem to work, even though when I `console.log` the variables, it pulls through the correct numbers.

Any ideas? Could it be because its a variable inside an array of another variable?

```
$('.doughnut').each(function(){
    var rating = $(this).attr('data-rating');
    var ratingDifference = 5 - rating;
    var data = [
        {
            value: rating,
            color: "rgba(129,129,129,0.5)"
        },
        {
            value: ratingDifference,
            color: "rgba(129,129,129,0.1)"
        }
    ];

    var options = { segmentShowStroke : false, }

    console.log('Rating: ' + rating);
    console.log('Difference: ' + ratingDifference);

    $(this).one('inview', function (event, visible) {
        if (visible == true) {
            new Chart($(this)[0].getContext('2d')).Doughnut(data,options);
        } else {
        }
    });
});
```

Update:
The console.log shows this at the moment: 
Rating: 3 
Difference: 2 
Rating: 1
Difference: 4 
Rating: 5 
Difference: 0 
Rating: 5 
Difference: 0

Comment: can you show me what is the output in console.log? and how you put static number?

Comment: You should remove the trailing comma on `segmentShowStroke`. Not saying it's the cause of your problem, but IE throws errros for fun when it detects hanging commas.

Comment: @Dh... The console.log shows this at the moment: Rating: 3 Difference: 2 Rating: 1 Difference: 4 Rating: 5 Difference: 0 Rating: 5 Difference: 0